# How do I design a high powered micro-controlled PID with triacs

Tags: microcontroller, triac, pid-controller, heatsink

I'm trying to build a micro-controller controlled PID. So far I have found a few recipes for high powered AC voltage ( 10 - 15 Amps ). The first recipe I found involved Using A potentiometer, a capacitor, a resistor a triac an a diac as illustrated below, however this is an analogue controlled system.

The [second system](http://www.alfadex.com/2014/02/dimming-230v-ac-with-arduino-2/) involves measuring the 0 crossing with the controller, and using a opto-isolated Triac. The issue with the example shown is that it is designed for control a lamp ( 100 watts ) and I'm looking to control a 1500 watt heater. Can someone recommend a suitable opto-isolated Triac. I was considering using a relay, but I want smoother control over the heat, and I would be concerned that the relay would wear out pretty quick if switching on and off so frequently.

[image]

Comment: Please try to draw a [proper schematic](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using heater, then a better solution is to use PWM technique with zero cross SSR / triac, rather than dimming with phase control. The entire process won't "see" the difference if you choose for example a 10s PWM period and turn the opto triac with zero cross with a timer controlled output. The phase control also produces EMI and has nonlinear output vs. control phase angle, additionaly you need a zero cross detector.
It makes sense to use phase control for dimming lights or for motor control.

EDIT:
Difference between phase angle control and PWM control of a triac/SSR
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how phase control is different from what you are recommending...  Are you talking about tail edge control vs leading edge control of the waveform?

Comment: @AndrewSpott I have added the depiction of the difference.

Comment: Ah, that makes it more clear why you referenced the heater at the beginning.

Comment: Any recommendation on what components to use ?

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have shown is for a simple dimmer switch. It is not suitable for your application.

The simplest and safest solution is to use an opto-isolated solid state relay (SSR). A 1500 W heater is likely to have a thermal response measured in many seconds so we can use a simple on-off control system with variable duty-cycle to control the average power being sent to the heater. By making the switching cycle short (say 2 to 5 s) relative to the response time of the heater (tens of seconds) tight control of the temperature is possible.

[image]

*Figure 1. Adjusting heater power by varying the duty cycle of a mains on-off controller. The waveform is the 50 or 60 Hz mains voltage applied to the heater.*

So using the scheme of Figure 1 we can adjust the power from zero to 100% in steps of one mains half-cycle.

[image]

*Figure 2. A typical industrial grade SSR by [Crydom](http://crydom.com). These are available in zero-cross and non-zero-cross versions. (This one has an AC control input. For a micro-controlled application a DC input type would be used.*

For your application you want a zero-cross type which will, when triggered, wait until the next zero-cross of the mains before turning the TRIAC output on. This will minimise electromagnetic interference with nearby devices.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk6yzl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. Sensor, micro, SSR, fuse, supply and load.*

Normal safety and good layout rules apply.

- Keep mains away from low-voltage circuits.
- Mount the SSR on some sort of heatsinking.
- Don't skip the fuse.

Comment: To be honest, when I look up the industrial SSRs with a 10A - 15A rating, they are in the 100 dollar range. I should have been more specific, it's a heating coil within a popcorn popper, and it's actually more like 900W. It really has very little thermal mass, so  I don't think the long duty cycles will work, also there is a fan involved so it makes that issue worse. Why woud one choose a SSR over a octo - triac setup?

Comment: "_I should have been more specific ..._" Agreed. "_Why woud one choose a SSR over a octo - triac setup?_" It's an _opto_-triac. Look at the current ratings on the datasheet.

Comment: No need to condescending, it was a typo

Comment: What gave the impression of condescension? I have no way of knowing whether it was a typo or whether you thought that was the correct name. I have given you an amount of my time answering your question and you should have read the comment in the light of my answer. Bye.